# A quali "cappe" si riferisce questa frase?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Non so niente di te* di Paola Mastrocola ho letto questa frase:

> Grigio, dovessimo indicare un colore, come son quei cieli nuvoli e nebbiosi, *incombenti come cappe*.

Non riesco a capire il senso della parola "cappe" nell'espressione "incombenti come cappe": a quali "cappe" si riferisce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il significato è metaforico: è un'espressione utilizzata per creare un'atmosfera di oppressione, come si evince da quanto riporta il [dizionario](http://dizionari.repubblica.it/Italiano/C/cappa.php) de *La Repubblica*, in particolare alla voce n°3:

> 3 fig. **Oppressione, peso**: una c. di nuvole, di calore, di nebbia
>   || *Trovarsi sotto una cappa di piombo*, oppresso da un'atmosfera soffocante.

Comment: Benvenuta su Italian.SE, @Mariella, e grazie mille della risposta!

Comment: Grazie a lei! Sono felice di apprendere che è una Fisica Teorica, tra le altre cose. :)

Comment: Mariella, solitamente qui [ci diamo del tu](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/9/ci-diamo-del-tu).